# Concatening in a specific order given by a number

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to concatenate the `Product` name in the given `Product_order` by `ID`.

Therefore, I should get something like: `CC-TC-CA` for ID 1.

Comment: This is possible, but it's usually best done in the client application.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `string_agg()`- it'll work sql server 2016+

```
select id, string_Agg(product,',') as pname
from tablename
group by id
```

OR you can use `stuff()`

```
SELECT id,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + product
              FROM tablename AS T1
              WHERE  T1.id = T2.id
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM   tablename AS T2
GROUP  BY id
```

Comment: I have SSMS 2017 and string_agg doesnt work. Also, STUFF does the job but it doesnt order in the desired order.

Comment: Add an order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a stored procedure instead of a single query the += operator can do what you're looking for.

```
DECLARE @Product_order VARCHAR(100) = '';
SELECT @Product_order += Product + '-' FROM [table] WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY Product_Order;
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Product_order, 0, LEN(@Product_order));
```

Update: I've learned that returning multiple rows and using in an assignment in the select clause is unsupported behavior in SQL Server.

Comment: I wish i could, but i cant